# Reduce the parameters of WordPress CURL

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, zoho

I am following the [Zoho WorkDrive API docs](https://workdrive.zoho.com/apidocs/v1/filesfolders/uploadfile) to upload a file.

When I use simple PHP to post via curl:

```
$folderId = 'xxxx';
$token    = 'xxxx';
$filepath = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Pictures\\test-file.jpg';

$realPath = realpath( $filepath );
$content  = curl_file_create( $realPath );

//the parameters
$postFields = array(
  'filename'            => 'test.jpg',
  'parent_id'           => $folderId,
  'override-name-exist' => 'true',
  'content'             => $content
 );

$curl_url = 'https://workdrive.zoho.com/api/v1/upload';
$curl_var = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl_var, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url );
curl_setopt( $curl_var, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt( $curl_var, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $curl_var, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
curl_setopt( $curl_var, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields );
curl_setopt( $curl_var, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
  'cache-control: no-cache'
) );
$response = curl_exec( $curl_var );
curl_close( $curl_var );
echo $response;
```

I can successfully Upload the file.

However when I use WordPress Curl:

```
$folderId = 'xxxx';
$token    = 'xxxx';
$filepath = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Pictures\\test-file.jpg';
$url      = 'https://workdrive.zoho.com/api/v1/upload';

$realPath = realpath( $filepath );
$content  = curl_file_create( $realPath );

//the parameters
$postFields = array( 
  'filename'            => 'test.jpg',
  'parent_id'           => $folderId,
  'override-name-exist' => 'true',
  'content'             => $content
);

$send = array(
  'headers' => array(
    'cache-control'  => 'no-cache',
    'authorization'  => 'Bearer ' . $token,
  ),
  'body' => $postFields
);

$response = wp_remote_post( $url, $send );
if (
  is_wp_error( $response ) ||
  wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) != 200 ) {
  error_log( print_r( $response, true ) );
}

return json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
```

All I keep getting is:

```
{"errors":[{"id":"F6012","title":"Number of parameters is more than specified"}]}
```

I have tried adding false on some params, in attempt to reduce them:

```
...
$send = array(
  ...
  'body' => $postFields,
  /**
   * I found the following in the WP_Http definition,
   * in attempt to reduce parameters.
   * 
   * Adding or removing the following, does not change the result
   */
  'user-agent' => false,
  'sslverify' => false,
  'sslcertificates' => false,
  'redirection' => false,
  '_redirection' => false,
  'decompress' => false,
);
...
```

My question is, how to reduce the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

After combing the WordPress Core code, here are my findings:

1. `wp_remote_post( $url, $body )` is defined in `http.php` which calls
   `$http->post( $url, $args )`
2. `$http` is defined as `_wp_http_get_object()` in `http.php` which calls
   `new WP_Http`
3. `post( $url, $args = array() )` is defined in `class WP_Http` which calls `request( $url, $parsed_args )`
4. `request( $url, $parsed_args )` is defined in `class WP_Http` which calls `WpOrg\Requests\Requests::request(...)`
5. `request(...)` is defined in `class Requests` which calls `$transport->request(...)`
6. ***Skipping ahead:*** `$transport` is uses `class Curl`, so that `$transport->request(...)` is defined in `class Curl` which calls `$this->setup_handle(...)`
7. `setup_handle(...)` does the adding of options to Curl. Here I discover that `$data = http_build_query($data, '', '&');` where `$data = $body` from point 1.

Now, when I add `$postFields = http_build_query($postFields, '', '&')` to the simple PHP Curl request, I get the same error (*F6012*). When I remove it, the file uploads.

Therefore the WordPress core has the body hardcoded to build a query (`http_build_query`).

Now to find out if WordPress can have it as an option in their next version (e.g. `'query_body' => false`)

Comment: Added a ticket requesting this: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/60658#ticket